# Derive a recursive formula using integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Straightforward integration of $$F(x, n)=\int \frac{x^n}{(x-a)^\alpha}dx$$ yields quite a cryptic formula with a hypergeometric function which is not defined given my data (goes infinite), and since I'm using it as a part of some numeric computation it's not acceptable.

I have been advised to derive a recursive formula using integration by parts, but calculus classes are long gone and I struggle with what should be $u$ and $v$ correspondingly.

To be more precise, we're looking for derivation of $F(x, n)$ via $F(x,n-1)$. $F(x, 0)$ is trivial and therefore we will have nice looking algorithm to compute $F(x,n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change of variables $y=x-a$ gives you

$$ \eqalign{F(y+a,n) &= \int \frac{(y+a)^n}{y^\alpha} \; dy\cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^{n-k}\int y^{k-\alpha}\; dy\cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^{n-k} \frac{y^{k-\alpha+1}}{k-\alpha+1} + C }$$
(except, if $k-\alpha+1 = 0$, replace $y^0/0$ by $\log(y)$).

Comment: That's even better!